# How to get the Configuration and Platform of a Referenced Project in MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

I'm creating a custom UI installer with Wix's Burn bootstrapper for a x86/x64 application. In the solution are 4 projects:

- App to be installed
- Wix Installer
- Wix Bootstrapper
- Custom UI

For both Wix projects, I edit the `.Wixproj` files (unload project -> edit project file) and use the BeforeBuild and AfterBuild to publish and rename their respective WPF projects to ensure everything is current and orderly. For instance, the final **Setup.exe** can be named something descriptive like **Setup-[AppToInstall's version]-Debug-x64.exe**.

**The Problem**

AFAIK, the bootstrapper projects and any custom UI must be 32-bit, while the App project and Wix Installer don't have that limitation. So in the bootstrapper project file, I can't ever use the `$(Platform)` variable because it will always be the bootstrapper's platform, which will always be x86. But what if I want to build the x64 version?

So I need a way to get the 'AppToInstall's' platform in the `.Wixproj`; something like this:

```
<GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\appToInstall\bin\$(appToInstall.Configuration)\netcoreapp3.1\win-$(AppToInstall.Platform)\publish\AppToInstall.dll">
         <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AppAssemblyVersion" />
</GetAssemblyIdentity>
```

Wix has handy variables for this (i.e `$(var.AppToInstall.Platform)`) that can be used inside the `Bundle.wxs` if the `AppToInstall.cproj` is referenced, but these can't be used directly in the `.Wixproj` file. How can this be done?

Comment: A little confused. Do you mean use MSBuild variables which is similar to Wix’s `$(var.AppToInstall.Platform)` in your App’s project file? But looks like you want to get your App project’s configurations in bootstrapper’s project file? So which project file are you going to modify? `.Wixproj` file? Besides, if you change to use the certain path instead of using `..\...\$(….)\...`, does the sample of MSBuild codes partly work under this specific circumstance?

Comment: I edited the question in hopes that it's more clear. Ya, I want to modify the `.Wixproj` file to get the App project's configuration/platform/version. It partly works, yes, but if say I set the configuration to `Debug/x64` the bootstrapper can't work as a x64 project, but if I set it to `Debug/x86`, then I will never get the x64 version of the app in the installer.

Comment: Though Wix provides $(var.AppToInstall.Platform), there is no way to get one project’s configuration/platform in another project’s project file by using normal MSBuild.

Comment: Well is there a solution or workaround? I was thinking that maybe you could set all of the projects to follow the solution's active configurations, but then in the .Wixproj set a condition where if the solution's platform is x64, then it should build as x86?

Comment: Actually I do consider the workaround, I start from MSBuild side, but the key thing is that MSBuild doesn’t provide a macro like which Wix provides, so the truly running configuration/platform is hard to get. I have read what you mentioned, looks good, just one thing, MSBuild doesn’t have a macro to access the **active solution configuration/platform**. So when you set a condition, this may be hard to work.